# how to add specific elements of a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have:

```
([(5,2),(7,2)],[(5,1),(7,3),(11,1)])
```

I need to add the second elements having the same first element.

output:`[(5,3),(7,5),(11,1)]`

Comment: Please show us a minimal, complete, verifiable example of what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use-case for `collections.Counter`...

```
from collections import Counter
tup = ([(5,2),(7,2)], [(5,1),(7,3),(11,1)])
counts = sum((Counter(dict(sublist)) for sublist in tup), Counter())
result = list(counts.items()) 
print(result)
```

One downside here is that you'll lose the order of the inputs.  They *appear* to be sorted by the key, so you could just sort the items:

```
result = sorted(counts.items())
```

---

A `Counter` is a dictionary whose purpose is to hold the "counts" of bins.  Counts are cleverly designed so that you can simply add them together (which adds the counts "bin-wise" -- If a bin isn't present in both Counters, the missing bin's value is assumed to be 0).  So, that explains why we can use `sum` on a bunch of counters to get a dictionary that has the values that you want.  Unfortunately for this solution, a `Counter` can't be instantiated by using an iterable that yields 2-item sequences like normal mappings ...,

```
Counter([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
```

would create a `Counter` with keys `(1, 2)` and `(3, 4)` -- Both values would be 1.  It does work as expected if you create it with a mapping however:

```
Counter(dict([(1, 2), (3, 4)]))
```

creates a `Counter` with keys `1` and `3` (and values `2` and `4`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code: (Brute force, may be..)

```
dt = {}
tp = ([(5,2),(7,2)],[(5,1),(7,3),(11,1)])
for ls in tp:
  for t in ls:
    dt[t[0]] = dt[t[0]] + t[1] if t[0] in dt else t[1]
print dt.items()
```

---

The approach taken here is to loop through the list of tuples and store the tuple's data as a dictionary, wherein the 1st element in the tuple `t[0]` is the `key` and the 2nd element `t[1]` is the `value`.
Upon iteration, every time the same key is found in the tuple's 1st element, add the value with the tuple's 2nd element. In the end, we will have a dictionary `dt` with all the `key`, `value` pairs as required. Convert this dictionary to list of tuples `dt.items()` and we have our output.

Comment: could you please explain further?

Comment: @zaolee_dragon: Updated explanation in the answer.